# How often are "Links to Your Site" updated in the Google Webmaster tool?

Tags: google-search-console, backlinks

How often are "Links to Your Site" updated in the Google Webmaster tool?

I found [this thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmasters/ohaTlZjhuVg) with various replies on the matter, from "every few days" and "around 20 to 30 days" to "backlinks to my website that were removed 9 months ago". That doesn't really help much.

Are there some more precise sources? A blog post of some SEO company that did some research on this? Even some information put out there by Google?

Comment: I do not think there is a set or even rough interval which is what the question implies and people tend to look for. It takes time to discover links since the Internet is so vast and webmaster tools tends to lag a bit. To answer your question, I have seen the number change day to day for few days. But that is not a reflection of being real-time as much as the data changing. So it does have the potential to change daily, but because it takes time to discover new links it changes when the data is updated in the database which may not be often.

Comment: Google Webmaster Tools is hugely unreliable in certain areas, and noticeably very lagged behind. The time links are reported you may have already lost those links, its pretty much a useless feature and I recommend you using a paid service that tracks links as Google does not have any obligation to return accurate or fast results.

Answer (score 5):

From my experience the reply to this question is: it depends.

And it depends on a lot of things:

1. How much traffic your site has? If you have a lot, it can be reviewed daily.
2. How many links your site has? If you have a lot, the crawlers will follow them and reach your site more often.

For what I saw, I managed a site with +200k users / day and the results were updated within a day. Smaller sites of about 500 uniques / day is more like weekly.

The fastest tool I used to check links is without a doubt `www.ahrefs.com`.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience i have seen the all domain page update every 4 days to a week (it varies). The latest links list will update first before displaying on the all domain list. My site has around 401 refering domains in webmaster.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it varies from site to site and depends much on how frequently you update your site. Suppose you have a site where you publish fresh content regularly then the changes are more that crawler will visit it more frequently. If your site doesn't have too much content then it varies from few weeks to months.
2nd thing it depends on the traffic as well that how well you rank for your keywords. In short it depends on the site overall authority, traffic that forces the crawler to visit more frequently.