# Google not picking up backlinks

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, backlinks

Google isn't picking up backlinks to my site.

I recently got linked from 2 prominent websites. This happened about 8 days ago. However Google Search Console does not show these sites in Search Traffic > Links to your site. I checked and these websites are indexed every day by Google.

What could be going on? Is there anything I can do about this?

When I look at the source of these sites, the links looks like:

```
<a href="https://www.redmatterapp.com" target="_blank">www.redmatterapp.com</a>
```

My site is protected by SSL and the links link the 'https'. Could that possibly be an issue?

Comment: It may take quite some time for Google to see these back links. In addition, Search Console can be damned slow in showing back links if they even show them at all. This is nothing to worry about. It is a short-coming, granted. It is a reality that we have to live with.

Comment: See also: [How often are “Links to Your Site” updated in the Google Webmaster tool?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/71453/how-often-are-links-to-your-site-updated-in-the-google-webmaster-tool)

Answer (score 1):

The [help page for links to your site](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/55281?hl=en) states:

> Not all links to your site may be listed. This is normal.

The list in Search Console has never been complete.   When links do appear, it often takes weeks or months from when they were created.

Just because the links don't appear, it doesn't mean that Google isn't seeing them or isn't counting them.